# Insert SQL statement not working on button press, but other statements do

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In the Code below, the 'Insert into Accounting' command does not work, but the Insert command before that and the Update command after does work. Before updating, The user of the program selects a row from a data grid, and the values from the datagrid transfer to the textboxes.

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtProdName.Text != "" && txtProdPrice.Text != "" && txtProdSupplier.Text != "")
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Update Product?", "Update Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                double PricePast = 0;
                double.TryParse(dataSupply.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ProdPriceSupply"].Value.ToString(), out PricePast);
                if (double.Parse(txtProdPrice.Text) != PricePast)
                {
                    int PastQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(dataSupply.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ProdQuantitySupply"].Value);

                    DateTime ProdPriceDate = DateTime.Now;
                    string ProdPriceDateString= ProdPriceDate.ToString("MM-yyyy");
                    con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Prices 
                                        (ProdIDPrice,PriceDate,PastPrice,PriceQuantity,PriceDateMonth)
                                                Values
                                        ('" + txtProdID.Text + "','" + ProdPriceDate + "','" + PricePast + "','"+PastQuantity+"','"+ProdPriceDateString+"');", con);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();


                    con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Accounting 
                                    (AcctTotalPrice,AcctDateMonth,AcctQuantity)
                                     VALUES
                                     ('" + txtProdPrice.Text + "','" + ProdPriceDateString + "','1')", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();


                    con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Update Supply Set ProdConstantQuantity = 1, ProdQuantity = ProdQuantity + '"+PastQuantity
                                          +"' where ProdID = '"+txtProdID.Text+"';", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close(); 
                }
```

Comment: Enclose the code in a try..catch and check for the exception details

Comment: Use Parameterized queries to avoid Sql Injection. What is the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

Make the value '1' for `AcctQuantity` an integer `1` instead of it being inside quotes.